# HP ProLiant DL360e Gen8 raid card error 347

Tags: raid, hp, hardware-raid

I just got a used HP ProLiant DL360e Gen8 and the cache was bad on the P222 raid card in it. The people I bought it from sent a new cache and battery.

I added it today and now it says cache for smart array p222 in slot 1 is not configured. But the green light is on the cache so it's got power. And the system sees it.

The only thing I can find says the battery is bad. But the light is on so I don't think that's it.

I checked every setting and ready 50 pages deep in Google.

Thanks,
Charles

Answer (score 2):

You have to go into the Intelligent Provisioning on the server or the HP Smart Storage Administrator and configure the cache.